# node.js as service for mobile + adminisrtation panel with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Currently we have mobile app that calls some "APIs" (no backedn yet).
I wonder if it would be ok to use node.js (never used before, I am .net developer) as service (mobile app would call node.js APIs).

And for some dashboard for administrating application, I could try to use angular+node.js.

I have started to learn node.js and angular just a day ago and I wonder if this would work for purpose above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! Nodejs RESTful API or web services can be used/called by mobile app.

I have developed web-Application & APIs for mobile app on Nodejs, Angularjs,  Postgres...
which maintains & used by

- Admin Panel
- Dashboards
- Generating reports (As BI Tools)
- Handling thousands of users concurrently & lots more!
  **Performance is superb! Work like charm**

Refer below link, to develop web services for mobile app using nodejs

[Designing a RESTful API with Node and Postgres](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/#.WkS3IXWCw8p)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to use the MEAN Stack, check out this blog

https://rclayton.silvrback.com/means-great-but-then-you-grow-up ,

to get the pros and cons regarding the stack usage. You will get rapid development using the stack but need to tradeoff on some features that may be required in the long run.
I just want to say, research before you start your project, because changing the technology afterwards is a huge waste of time and money.

Comment: Btw, I cannot find much information on tradoffs in long run. Basicaly, most of resources say that MEAN stack is a good decision also in long run.